# Checking Subprocesses in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run one python program from another using `subprocess`. Here's the function I've got so far:

```
def runProcess(exe):
p = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while(True):
  retcode = p.poll() #returns None while subprocess is running
  line = p.stdout.readline()
  yield line
  if(retcode is not None):
    break
```

then i run:

```
for line in runProcess('python myotherprogram.py'): print line
```

but I get an `OS error: no such file`, but it doesn't tell me what file doesn't exist. It's baffling. Any suggestions? I can use the `runProcess` function for normal terminal commands, such as `ls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What doesn't exist is a single executable named `python myotherprogram.py`. To specify arguments, you need to provide a list consisting of the command and its argument, such as with `runProcess(["python", "myotherprogram.py"])`, or specify `shell=True` to the `Popen` constructor.

The relevant quote from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> *args* should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single
>   string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in *args*
>   if *args* is a sequence. *If* args is a string, the interpretation is
>   platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable
>   arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless
>   otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass *args* as a sequence.
>
> On Unix, if *args* is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or
>   path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done if not
>   passing arguments to the program.